# C# how to make it so that a function that can sort strings or ints without overloading?

Tags: c#, sorting, oop, overloading, comparator

As the title says, I had to write some code to sort either array/list of strings or integers. My OOP knowledge is really rusty since I haven't used C#/Java for a long while.

Is there a way to make it so I just need to code one function so that I don't have to overload the function

(e.g InsertSort(int [] arr) and InsertSort(string [] arr))

I heard something about using IComparable or Comparator and I took a look at the documentation of both but they seems to me that those are like more for Objects.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a Google of `dynamic` or `generics`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic methods should be your friend here. Generics allow you to defer the specification of types used in method until actually used in program. You can read more on Generic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).

```
public T[] InsertSort<T>(T[] source)
{
// Do something

}
```

This can be invoked using strings/int arrays as following.

```
var intArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
var stringArray = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
InsertSort(intArray);
InsertSort(stringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get started, you might try something like this method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertSort<T>(IEnumerable<T> tmp)
{
  //... Perform sorting
  //... Return the sorted results as IEnumerable 
}
```

You'll be able to send in a list or an array of the types you choose.

Usage:

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>();
var sortedListA = InsertSort(listA);

string[] arrA = new string[5];
var sortedArrayA = InsertSort(arrA);
```